# Parse integer in base 10 to base 16 in Squirrel

Tags: squirrel

How should I do base 10 to base 16 integer conversion in Squirrel? In Javascript I can do this with: `parseInt("ff", 16)`.

I'm trying to do a HEX color code to RGB calculator for an Electric Imp. `#ffaacc`would be split into 3 parts (`ff`, `aa` and `cc`). I would then calculate these to base 10 integers and achieve RGB(255, 170, 204). These numbers I will then use to control an RGB led with PWM.

Comment: It looks like you're going to have to write some code if Squirrel doesn't have `strtol`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one approach using [array.find](http://squirrel-lang.org/doc/squirrel3.html#d0e3299) (and [format](http://squirrel-lang.org/doc/sqstdlib3.html#d0e2187) for reversal):

```
local lookup = ['0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9',
                'a','b','c','d','e','f']
local hex = "7f"
local dec = lookup.find(hex[0]) * 0x10 + lookup.find(hex[1])
server.log(format("%s -> %d -> %02x", hex, dec, dec))
```

Answer (score 3):

Try String tointeger() function.

```
local s = "ff";
print (s.tointeger(16));
```

If you want convert conversely, try format() function.

```
local i = 255;
print (format("%x", i));
```